# Communication between instances of the same directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Lets assume I am having a directive `my-popup` which is a popup box. In a view I'm using multiple instances of this same directive. I want to let other popup boxes to know when I've clicked a button or on completion of certain async operations on any of the other instances of the directive and perform the relative operations on them.

In such case what is the best way to get this communication happen?

Comment: As per my opinion you have to use $on.event of angular js

Comment: @GautamPatadiya, please see my updated question

Comment: Use a Service that controls all the "messaging" (function calls) between all your instances instead of directly communicating between then with broadcasts. Better architecture IMHO.

Comment: Read this: http://csharperimage.jeremylikness.com/2014/12/the-top-5-mistakes-angularjs-developers.html - especially the "Overusing $broadcast and $emit" section.

Answer (score 0):

Create a broadcast for the click event, and put together a function that listens to that event, all these in the directive, and then Voila! problem solved.